# How to solve 504 gateway timeout error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
exports.deleteCheckPhoto = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  const input = req.body.photoPath;

  const pattern = /^\.\/public\/uploads\/\d{4}\/\d{2}$/;

  // Check if the input matches the pattern
  if (!pattern.test(input)) {
    // Input is in the correct format
    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'InValid photoPath format' });
  } 

  const PAGE_SIZE = req.body.pageSize || 50; // Set the page size to a reasonable value
  const FETCH_SIZE = req.body.limit || 10; // Set the number of photos to fetch in each call

  try {
    const memberOrNot = await Member.find({
      $or: [
        { photo1Path: input },
        { photo2Path: input },
        { photo3Path: input },
        { photo4Path: input },
        { photo5Path: input },
      ]
    });

    const folderPath = input;
    const files = await fsPromises.readdir(folderPath);

    // Process files in batches
    let offset = 0;
    let fetchedPhotos = [];

    while (offset < files.length && fetchedPhotos.length < FETCH_SIZE) {
      const batch = files.slice(offset, offset + PAGE_SIZE);
      const serverPhotos = batch.filter(file => {
        return !memberOrNot.some(member =>
          [member.photo1, member.photo2, member.photo3, member.photo4, member.photo5].includes(file)
        );
      });

      fetchedPhotos = fetchedPhotos.concat(serverPhotos.slice(0, FETCH_SIZE - fetchedPhotos.length));

      offset += PAGE_SIZE;
    }

    // Send the response if photos were fetched
    if (fetchedPhotos.length > 0) {
      sendResponse(res, fetchedPhotos.length, fetchedPhotos);
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: `No photos were fetched from ${folderPath}`,
      });
    }
  } catch (catchError) {
    console.error('Error fetching memberOrNot:', catchError);
    if (!res.headersSent) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error fetching memberOrNot',
      });
    }
  }
});
```

const files = await fsPromises.readdir(folderPath);

The memberOrNot array has some values. Check those  memberOrNot  Record .photo1, photo2, photo3, poto4, and photo5 fields and compare them to the files array to see if those photo1, photo2, photo3, poto4, and photo5 values exist on the server, if it exists leave it. but when comparing those (photo 1, photo 2, photo 3, photo 4, and photo 5) values that do not exist in the file array, delete those values on the server.

The code is working, but in the files  array have 15,000 records.so it makes a timeout error or makes other APIs slow. How do I solve this?

Comment: increase the gateway timeout as appropriate or decrease the amount of time the code takes